# iOS Are custom frameworks statically linked?

Tags: ios

I have created a custom iOS Cocoa Touch framework and added it as part of "Link binary with Libraries" in another project. Is this custom framework statically or dynamically linked?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I need to code-sign the framework or does it get signed when the app is signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom framework is dynamically linked if you didn't take steps to make it static. The framework bundle (including the dynamic library) is copied into your app's bundle.